# sorting an array list of int arrays in terms of the first and the second element of the int arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

```
ArrayList<int[]> segment = new Arraylist<int[]>();
segment.add(new int[]{2,3,1});
segment.add(new int[]{2,1,1});
segment.add(new int[]{1,1,1});
segment.add(new int[]{2,4,1});
segment.add(new int[]{3,3,1});
```

What I want to do is sort this ArrayLists according to the first element of each array and if the element is same do the sorting according to the 2nd element of the array/arrays

For instance the above lines of code should be modified to,
(1,1,1)
(2,1,1)
(2,3,1)
(2,4,1)
(3,3,1)

this is what i have so far in temrs of solving this,

```
    public static void SortSegment(ArrayList<int[]> segment){
        Collections.sort(segment, new Comparator<int[]>() {
             public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
                  return (a[0] - b[0]);
             }
        });
    }
```

this piece of code sorts the arraylist of int arrays according to the first element of each of the int arrays.
How do i modify it to work for cases where the first element is the same so it takes into consideration the 2nd element?

thanks.

Comment: Are there always 3 elements in each int array?

Comment: Just check first if the 1st elements are equal. If yes, compare the 2nd ones. Else keep what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if(a[0] - b[0]==0) //Like the first row of the matrix if so, we proceed to the next to know which is lower
```

code complete

```
Collections.sort(segment, new Comparator<int[]>() {
         public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
              if(a[0] - b[0]==0) //if equals
              {
                  return a[1]-b[1];//recompare 
              }
              else
                  return a[0]-b[0];
         }
    });
```

Comment: Hi do you mind to explain a little bit more on the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `Comparator` interface has some useful utility (default) methods in Java 8 that are useful for custom sorting:

```
segment.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(el -> el[0]).thenComparingInt(el -> el[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
segments.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0])
    .thenComparing(a -> a[1])
    .thenComparing(a -> a[2]));
```